# What propels the photon, it must be some force?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

If the classification of "photon" is universal then surely the energy force requirements for any protons initial "take off" would likewise. Fire flies and exploding stars? Surely the propellant force of the proton must be measurable. Protons have form so something is holding it together, that form has been launched, where's the equal and opposite reactions?

Comment: F = m a, photons have no m and no a, so no f

Comment: The probability of an photon being exchanged between two particles,  such as electrons, is directly proportional, on a classical level, to Coulomb's law.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law

Comment: On an atomic level, fire flies and exploding stars are pretty much the same thing, apart from the number and density of atoms, in relation to your question.

Comment: I think there are some typos in your question. Are you asking about photons or protons? The photon is sometimes described as the carrier particle of the electromagnetic force. It's a fundamental particle, it has no parts that need to be held together.

Comment: What is an "energy force requirement"?

Answer (score 1):

Photons have no mass so no force and no acceleration.

You have to think of a photon as created instantaneously travelling at the speed of light - which is a bit tricky in classical mechanics.

They don't really feel forces. They are affected by gravity, but in General relativity that just means the photons think they are travelling in a straight line through space but the space is curved